# how to put a string value from one Application Db Context to another?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'v declared a var to select elements from db context named `BUGS`(Table).

i set it to include all the columns, there is a foreign key named `ProjectsPId`.

It can return the id (The foreign key), but it returns "null" if we call projects.name for example.

So, i declared a `var ("BUGS1" = context.bugs)` this give me the value of project.name with no problems.

How i can put the "Project Name" value from the `var bugs1` to the var bugs.

i'v tried to do this:

`bugs.Where(b => b.Projects.PName) = bugs1.Where(c => c.Projects.PName);`

this give me an error

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? id, string sortOrder, string searchString)
        {
            var bugs1 = _context.BugsSummary;
             var bugs = from b in _context.BugsSummary
                       select b;
            {


                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
                {
                    bugs = bugs.Where(b => b.Projects.PName.Contains(searchString)
                                           || b.Bug.Contains(searchString));
                }

                switch (sortOrder)
                {


                    case "name_desc":
                        bugs = bugs.OrderByDescending(b => b.Projects.PName);
                        break;
                    case "Date":
                        bugs = bugs.OrderBy(b => b.PublicationDate);
                        break;
                    case "date_desc":
                        bugs = bugs.OrderByDescending(b => b.PublicationDate);
                        break;
                    default:
                        bugs = bugs.OrderBy(b => b.Projects.PName);
                        break;

                }


                if (id > 0)
                {
                    bugs.Include(b => b.User).Include(b => b.Projects)

                        .Where(b => b.ProjectsPId == id)
                        ;
                }
                else
                {
                    bugs.Include(b => b.User).Include(b => b.Projects);
                }

                ViewData["DateSortParm"] = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
                ViewData["NameSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
                ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;
            }

            bugs.Where(b => b.Projects.PName) = bugs1.Where(c => c.Projects.PName);

            return View(await bugs.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, my friend. But I don't know why you need the bug1?

Comment: bug1 can give me the value of the string "project.name".

bug have "Null" value with project.name, i'm trying to put the bug1 project name in the bug "project name"

Comment: As I see, both bug and bug1 get the data from BugsSummary. Maybe bug return null data cause you are searching the project name.

Comment: no it's null becuase of something else, i don't know why bugs1 project.name is not null and bugs project name is null.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the initial value of the query, you need to use `Include` method to load related data like below :

```
 var bugs = from b in _context.BugsSummary.Include(b=>b.Projects)
            select b;
```

Then you don't need bug1 to pass the value of the string "project.name" to bugs

Comment: @YakaGgFa, I am glad to help you .Could you mark my reply as the answer ? This may help others who face the same or similar issue to find the answer quickly. Thanks!